# IIS - deleted parent of virtual directory but vDir still handling requests

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I wanted to delete a virtual directory which was under a folder which also would become useless once the vDir was remove, so I deleted the parent folder in explorer and refreshed the site.

Requests to the vDir path are still being handled! I need to remove the virtual directory but now its not showing in IIS to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate the folder in the filesystem and it will be shown in IIS (refresh), then delete the vDir.